# Powershell script to Install SW on VM or host using Application from SCCM 2012..?

Tags: powershell, cloud, sccm

I am using Orchestrator runbook in which there is a ".net run script" which even runs Powershell script, i have to write a Powershellscript which Query the SCCM 2012 for the SW(given as parameter) and install it on the VM (given as parameter). i have already list of Softwares as an application in the Software Library of SCCM 2012.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Orchestrator a much simpler solution (more in keeping with Orchestrator) would be to install the "System Center Integration Pack for System Center 2012 Configuration Manager" and use the activities defined there:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh967537.aspx
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=28725

You can either:

- Add the machine to an existing collection that already has deployments active for the software you want installing - Use the "Add Collection Rule" activity to add the machine to the correct collection: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh967533
- Create a new collection specifically for the machine and deploy applications to the collection using the "Create Collection" and "Deploy Application" activities: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh967526 and http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh967531